# Rails - Action cable : Broadcasting to specific resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, actioncable

I am using action cable and rails 6.
I am trying to broadcast messages to a particular organization.
My client js code picks up the organization id on the page an creates a subscription on the organization channel, passing up the organization_id.

```
const organizationID = document.getElementById("organization-wrapper").dataset.organizationId
  consumer.subscriptions.create({
    channel: "OrganizationChannel",
    organization_id: organizationID
  },{
    connected() {
      console.log('connected')
    },
    received(data) {
      alert("hey")
      const budgetSpentCents = parseInt(data['budget_spent_cents'])
      const budgetSpentUnit = budgetSpentCents / 100.0
      const trainingBudgetTotal = document.getElementById('training-budget-total')
      const currentTrainingBudgetTotal = parseInt(trainingBudgetTotal.textContent)
      trainingBudgetTotal.textContent = currentTrainingBudgetTotal + budgetSpentUnit
    }
```

This works well, and I can see the ruby channel code being executed :

```
class OrganizationChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    binding.pry
    organization = Organization.find(params[:organization_id])
    stream_from organization
  end

  def unsubscribed
    stop_all_streams
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end
end
```

However I am stuck when I try to broadcast to that particular client (organization). Here 's my attempt :

```
  OrganizationChannel.broadcast_to(
          Organization.first,
          budget_spent_cents: Registration.last&.training_budget_transaction&.total_cents
        )
```

which returns 0 and

```
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to organization:Z2lkOi8veXVub28vT3JnYW5pemF0aW9uLzE: {:budget_spent_cents=>-5000}
```

the `received(data)` hook in my client code is never executed... Im not sure why ? My guess is because `Z2lkOi8veXVub28vT3JnYW5pemF0aW9uLzE` is not the actual id of the organization (what is that string actually ?) and it doesnt find the proper channel to broadcast to.

How would you setup the broadcasting right in that situation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Z2lkOi8veXVub28vT3JnYW5pemF0aW9uLzE` is the global id for the organization you are testing with. `organization:Z2lkOi8veXVub28vT3JnYW5pemF0aW9uLzE` is the channel name generated and used by the `OrganizationChannel.broadcast_to` method based on the arguments you are passing.

On your `OrganizationChannel` class, instead of using `stream_from organization` use `stream_for organization`. That will tell the client to properly stream from the `organization:#{global_id}` channel.

Comment: Is there a method to call on an instance of organization to get this global_id ?

Comment: It worked. however Im a bit confused as to how this works. The channel is called ```organization:#{global_id}``` but on the client/consumer side, I have   ```consumer.subscriptions.create({
    channel: "OrganizationChannel",
    organization_id: organizationID
  }``` which seems based on the organizationID (normal id). How are the 2 linked here ?

Comment: 1. To get the global id as used in the channel, you can use `to_gid_param` on your record.

2. `consumer.subscriptions.create({channel: "OrganizationChannel",  organization_id: organizationID}` tells your server to run the `subscribed` method on your `OrganizationChannel` class, passing `organization_id` as a parameter.
Then that method tells your client to listen on `organization:#{global_id}`  via the `stream_for`. Without the `stream_for`, your client won't listen. Sometimes this is ideal behavior. See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#example-1-user-appearances